# WinForm Listbox selected item centered vertically and expanded in height

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a custom Listbox in my winforms application to hold a long list of text. I am using the custom ListBox to have the selectedItem to be bigger in height than other items. The code for the listbox :

```
public class CustomListBox : System.Windows.Forms.ListBox
{
    int thisIndex = -1;

    public CustomListBox()
    {
        this.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
        this.SelectionMode = System.Windows.Forms.SelectionMode.One;

    }
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Highlight, e.Bounds);
            else
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
            Font myFont = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12f, FontStyle.Bold);

            object item = this.Items[e.Index];
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
            SizeF size = e.Graphics.MeasureString(item.ToString(), e.Font);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(), myFont, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds.Left + (e.Bounds.Width / 2 - size.Width / 2), e.Bounds.Top + (e.Bounds.Height / 2 - size.Height / 2));
            base.OnDrawItem(e);

        }
    }

    protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
        thisIndex = this.SelectedIndex;
        this.RecreateHandle();
    }

    protected override void OnMeasureItem(MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index > -1)
        {
            if (e.Index == thisIndex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("HELLOooooooo");
                e.ItemHeight = 70;
            }
            else
                e.ItemHeight = 45;
        }
        base.OnMeasureItem(e);
    }
}
```

The code does the trick. I want another functionality in the listbox, When I press the down arrow key to navigate through the list, I want the selecteditem of the listbox to start from the top, move to the center of the screen and remain there till the bottom of the list is visible on screen and then go to the last item. i.e, the selecteditem remains centered on screen other than in the very beginning and end of list.

I can make a default listbox to work this way changing the listbox.TopIndex value. However, with the customList OnSelectedIndexChanged() override, the scrolling feels elastic.

Any directions on how to have centered alligned and expanded selectedItem in a listbox at the same time?

Comment: You can set the [TopIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.topindex(v=vs.110).aspx) to a calculated value when you move the selected index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally if you want to change the height of some specific items **fixedly**, you can handle the event `ListBox.MeasureItem`, however your requirement shows that you want to change the height of the selected item which is very dynamic at runtime. I've tried this code and it works greatly, especially, if using the `Invalidate()` to update the listBox, there is a noticeable flicker but by calculating more carefully just the region in need to be updated (and pass it in to `Invalidate` method), we can reduce the flicker to nearly ZERO (smoothly). Now turn back to the main problem, the point is we can send the message `LB_SETITEMHEIGHT` to a listBox to change the height of an item. In fact this feature is not supported in winforms listBox, it only supports changing the height **for all the items** using the `ItemHeight` property, and this property is meaningful only when the `DrawMode` is not `Normal`. After setting the item height, we have to `Invalidate` the `ListBox` to update accordingly, as I said before, we should calculate the region in need to be updated to prevent flicker, otherwise simply call `listBox.Invalidate()` and there is a little flicker. Now is the code for you:

```
//your form constructor
public Form1(){
  InitializeComponent();
  listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
  listBox1.ItemHeight = 18;//setting this to change the height of all items
  listBoxWndProc = typeof(Control).GetMethod("WndProc", 
                                             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
  //the initial selected index is 0
  SetItemHeight(0, selectedItemHeight);
  listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;  

}
int selectedItemHeight = 25;
int lastSelectedIndex;
private System.Reflection.MethodInfo listBoxWndProc;
private void SetItemHeight(int index, int height) {
   var h = Math.Min(255, height);//the maximum height is 255
   //LB_SETITEMHEIGHT = 0x1a0
   Message msg = Message.Create(listBox1.Handle, 0x1a0, (IntPtr)index, (IntPtr)h);
   listBoxWndProc.Invoke(listBox1, new object[] { msg });
}
//handle the SelectedIndexChanged to update the selected item height
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
  //Reset the height of the last selected item
  SetItemHeight(lastSelectedIndex, listBox1.ItemHeight);
  int minIndex = Math.Min(lastSelectedIndex, listBox1.SelectedIndex);
  int maxIndex = Math.Max(lastSelectedIndex, listBox1.SelectedIndex);                
  lastSelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
  SetItemHeight(lastSelectedIndex, selectedItemHeight);
  var rect1 = listBox1.GetItemRectangle(minIndex);
  var rect2 = listBox1.GetItemRectangle(maxIndex);
  listBox1.Invalidate(new Rectangle(rect1.X, rect1.Y, 
                                    rect1.Width, rect2.Bottom - rect1.Top)); 
}
```

I'm not sure if your `DrawItem` event handler works together with my code above, if not, you can try the following code instead (tested):

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e){
  e.DrawBackground();
  if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Focus) == DrawItemState.Focus) 
       e.DrawFocusRectangle();
  //determine the font, if the item is selected, choose a large font size
  //I set it to 15, you can set it yourself accordingly to the selectedItemHeight
  bool selected = (e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected;
  var font = selected ? new Font(e.Font.FontFamily, 15, e.Font.Style) : e.Font;
  var color = selected ? SystemColors.HighlightText : e.ForeColor;
  //Draw the string, you can also provide some StringFormat to align text, ...
  using(var brush = new SolidBrush(color)){
    e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), font, brush, e.Bounds);
  }
}
```

[image]

Note that, I talked about sending message `LB_SETITEMHEIGHT`, but I used reflection to invoke the `WndProc` instead of using P/Invoke to call the `SendMessage` win32 api.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
TopIndex = Math.Max(0, SelectedIndex-VisibleItems/2);
```

Where `VisibleItems` is the amount of items visible at a time in the list.

Comment: Math.Min(0, SelectedIndex-VisibleItems/2) makes the topIndex to be zero always. I anyway understood the idea and approach works well in a default listbox, but for some reason, not in my custom lisbox. Atleast, i zeroed in on the problem :-)!

Comment: Changed it to Max (doh)

Comment: The answer works well with a default list. However, I want a listbox with selectedItem expanded in height, for which I am using a customListbox. Any idea how i can have both the functionality together? I have updated my question. Thanks